# Setting X/Y shadow offset values to 1 and -1 in advanced text window using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling, layer-file

I am trying to use a label expression with ArcGIS formatting tags to create a shadow on my text. I have done everything I need except assigning a value of 1 to X offset, and a value of -1 to Y offset.

Below is my code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "OCParcelsAPN selection", df) [0]
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"L:\GISLibrary\Scripts\Python\ReferenceLayers\OCParcels_selection.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, True)

del sourceLayer

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) [0]

if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    for lblclass in layer.labelClasses:
        lblclass.className = "ASSESSMENT"
        lblclass.expression = '"<FNT name=""Futura Md BT"" size=""6""> <CLR red=""255"" green=""255"" blue=""0"">" & [ASSESSMENT] & "</CLR> </FNT>"'
        lblclass.showClassLabels = True

        layer.showLabels = True

        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [@PolyGeo stated](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/158623/115), it is an ArcPy limitation.

The workaround is to configure these properties in a .lyr file on disk (once-off using ArcMap) and then use that layer file in the arcpy script.

In the case of your script, you are already using a layer file on disk, so this simply means updating these properties using ArcMap (once only) in the existing file you already reference here:

```
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"L:\GISLibrary\Scripts\Python\Reference         Layers\OCParcels_selection.lyr")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are changing font, color and size is by [using Text Formatting tags](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000000p000000):

> ArcGIS text formatting tags let you modify the formatting for a
>   portion of text. This lets you create mixed-format text where, for
>   example, one word in a sentence is underlined. Text formatting tags
>   can be used almost anywhere text is placed on or around the map in
>   ArcMap.

However, modifying shadow is not available within text formatting tags so I think you are up against an ArcPy limitation.  You could submit an ArcGIS Idea for this, but if you do, I recommend targeting ArcGIS Pro's arcpy.mp rather than the arcpy.mapping module of the ArcGIS 10.x architecture.

---

I suspect that in ArcGIS Pro this functionality may now be available to you from ArcPy by using [Python CIM Access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm).